# UNIX how to make my script delete multiple files and wildcards?

Tags: bash, unix

I was given the task of making a remove script that imitates the rm command. As you know, the rm command deletes all files if you were to type something like `rm file1 file2`. Using this example, my script would only delete file2. Can anyone help me on how to make it so my remove script would delete all files listed? My script is below. I apologise if its a little messy, I am new to coding.

```
    #!/bin/bash

       function directory(){
       #Checks if deleted directory & .restore.info file exists
       #If they don't exist, it creates them
       if [ ! -d ~/deleted ]
           then
               mkdir ~/deleted
       fi

      if [ ! -f ~/.restore.info ]
          then
              touch ~/.restore.info
      fi
      }

      function movefile(){
      #not currently using
      mv "$1" ~/deleted/$1
      echo "file moved to recycle bin"
      }

      function error_conditions(){
      #not currently using
      #Prints error messages and checks if file is in project directory
      if [ ! -f ~/project ]
          then
              echo "cannot remove $filename: no such file or directory"
      elif [ -d ~/project ]
              then
                  echo "cannot remove $filename: is a directory"
      else
          echo "missing operand"
      fi
      }

      function delete_file(){
      #Gets inode for filename
      #Takes user input and puts file wherever based on user input
      inode=$(stat -c%i "$filename")
      pwd=$(readlink -e $filename)
      if "$interactive"
          then
              if [ "$verbose" = true ]; then
                  read -p "Are you sure you want to delete $filename? " user_input
                      if [ $user_input == "y" ] || [ $user_input == "Y" ] || [ $user_input == "yes" ] || [ $user_input == "Yes" ];
                          then
                      mv $filename ~/deleted/${filename}_$inode
                      #moves deleted file to deleted directory (with inode at end)
                      echo ${filename}_$inode:$pwd>>~/.restore.info
                      #stores info of removed file in .restore.info (with path)
                      echo "removed '$filename'"
                          else
                          echo "Nothing has been deleted"
                      fi
              else
                  read -p "Are you sure you want to delete $filename? " user_input
                      if [ $user_input == "y" ] || [ $user_input == "Y" ] || [ $user_input == "yes" ] || [ $user_input == "Yes"];
                      then
                      mv "$filename" ~/deleted/${filename}_$inode
                      echo ${filename}_$inode:$pwd>>~/.restore.info
                      else
                      echo "Aborted"
              fi
          fi
      elif "$verbose"
          then
              mv "$filename" ~/deleted/${filename}_$inode
              echo ${filename}_$inode:$inode:pwd>>~/.restore.info
              echo "removed '$filename'"
      else
          mv "$filename" ~/deleted/${filename}_$inode
          echo ${filename}_$inode:$pwd>>~/.restore.info
          echo "Executed"
  fi
  }
  #Setting all flags to false
  interactive=false
  verbose=false
  recursive=false
  while getopts :ivr optionvar
  do
      case "$optionvar" in
          i) interactive=true;;
          v) verbose=true;;
          r) recursive=true;;
      esac
  done
  shift $((OPTIND-1)) #process arguments.
  #doing error commands with help of recursive
  for i in $*
      do
  filename=$i
  basefile=$(basename $i)
  if [ "$filename" == " " ];
      then
          echo "No filename provcided"
      elif [ -d $filename ];
          then
              if [ ! $recursive = true ];
                 then
                     echo "Directory name provided, please provide a file"
             fi
     elif [ ! -f $filename ];
         then
             echo "File does not exist"
     #   elif [ "$basefile" == "safe_rm" ]
     #   then
     #       echo "Attempting to delete safe_rm"
 fi
 done
 #################################M A I N###############################
 directory
 delete_file $*
 #error_conditions $* #- this gives me duplicate output lines
 #movefile "$@" - this gives me an unnecessary "mv: cannot stat" output line
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Your script is a bit long and you never explained what its problem is, therefore you are unlikely to get any help. Try to explain a *concrete* problem in detail and show us only the code related to that problem. Other than that, you might want to have a look at https://www.shellcheck.net/ a very helpful tool to avoid many pitfalls of bash.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to do a detailed code review of your whole script, but here are a few notes.

- You are looping over the arguments in the main part of your script, but then you're calling the delete function with multiple arguments. That function has no looping in it. Move the loop from `main()` to `delete_files()` (and note that I pluralized its name for clarity).
- And speaking of `main()`, you might as well encapsulate that code (option processing, function dispatch, etc.) in a function of that name, then at the bottom of your script have a line that calls it: `main "$@"`
- Don't use `$*` unless you need what it does and understand its use - instead use `"$@"` almost always and always quote it (with *very* rare exceptions)
- Use indentation consistently
- If your script doesn't need to be portable to shells other than Bash, then use Bash-specific features such as `[[ ]]` instead of `[ ]`
- You're using both methods of naming a function at the same time (`function f()`). Use one or the other - parens are preferred over using `function` - so `f () { ...; }`
- Use more quotes, some examples:
  `pwd=$(readlink -e "$filename")`
  `mv "$filename" ~/deleted/"${filename}_$inode"`
  `echo "${filename}_$inode:$pwd" >> ~/.restore.info`
- But I don't recommend using tilde (`~`) in scripts - use `$HOME` instead. And if you need to look up a user's home directory, use `getent` instead of other methods.